# Balancing data with numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I need to fix a unbalanced dataset for ML. I have 3 dataset, numpy arrays, with shapes that look like this:

```
MNIST pixel values: (45000, 28, 28, 1)
MFCC audio values: (45000, 93, 13)
Matching labels(45000, 1)
```

The matching labels dataset contains a true when the MNIST and MFCC values refer to the same digit (0-9). Because there are only around 4500 True values in the matching labels dataset, I'd like to find a way to balance this dataset.

We already tried using a custom loss function but that didnt work properly. We're open to suggestions and would like to use numpy to alter the datasets themselves.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? To split the 45000 samples into training/devel/test sets?

Comment: No this is purely the training set. I want to edit this training set to create a balanced set with as much True's as False's, so either delete False's or add True's to balance it out. I don't know what the best way is.

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts on this are you need to make a list of the True files, since it is the imbalanced class, then use that range for your MNIST and MFCC files for each class, and duplicate them or perform unique alterations (skew for images, flip, rescale, etc).  I am dealing with the same problem except no audio files.  Then append the original dataset with your altered data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).